# How to allow the user to access methods of a class

Tags: java, arrays, class, methods, java.util.scanner

I am working a programming project from Java textbook that says:

> The L&L bank can handle up to 30 customers who have savings accounts. Design and implement a program that manages the accounts. Keep track of key information and let each customer make deposits and withdrawals. Produce error messages for invalid transactions. Hint: You may want to base your accounts on the Account class from Chapter 4. Also provide a method to add 3 percent interest to all accounts whenever the method is invoked.

I am not certain on what the question is specifically asking but my guess is to allow and enable the user to add accounts, deposit, withdraw, add interest, get balance, and print the accounts being managed into an array. I am not entirely sure that I have to make an array but the whole chapter is on arrays.

My problem is that I am not sure how to enable the user to make an account
 (EX: `Account acct1 = new Account ("Ted Murphy", 72354, 102.56);`),

to deposit money (EX: `acct1.deposit (25.85);`),

withdraw money (EX: `acct3.withdraw (800.00, 0.0);`),

add interest (EX: `acct1.addInterest();`),

or to print an array for all the accounts.

Here is the Account class found in the Java textbook with all the methods:

```
//********************************************************************
//  Account.java       Author: Lewis/Loftus/Cocking
//
//  Represents a bank account with basic services such as deposit
//  and withdraw.
//********************************************************************

import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class Accounts
{



private NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

   private final double RATE = 0.035;  // interest rate of 3.5%

   private int acctNumber;
   private double balance;
   private String name;

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Sets up the account by defining its owner, account number,
   //  and initial balance.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public Accounts (String owner, int account, double initial)
   {
      name = owner;
      acctNumber = account;
      balance = initial;
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Validates the transaction, then deposits the specified amount
   //  into the account. Returns the new balance.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public double deposit (double amount)
   {
      if (amount < 0)  // deposit value is negative
      {
         System.out.println ();
         System.out.println ("Error: Deposit amount is invalid.");
         System.out.println (acctNumber + "  " + fmt.format(amount));
      }
      else
         balance = balance + amount;
      return balance;
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Validates the transaction, then withdraws the specified amount
   //  from the account. Returns the new balance.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------


     public double withdraw (double amount, double fee)
       {
          amount += fee;

      if (amount < 0)  // withdraw value is negative
      {
         System.out.println ();
         System.out.println ("Error: Withdraw amount is invalid.");
         System.out.println ("Account: " + acctNumber);
         System.out.println ("Requested: " + fmt.format(amount));
      }
      else
         if (amount > balance)  // withdraw value exceeds balance
         {
            System.out.println ();
            System.out.println ("Error: Insufficient funds.");
            System.out.println ("Account: " + acctNumber);
            System.out.println ("Requested: " + fmt.format(amount));
            System.out.println ("Available: " + fmt.format(balance));
         }
         else
            balance = balance - amount;

      return balance;
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Adds interest to the account and returns the new balance.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public double addInterest ()
   {
      balance += (balance * RATE);
      return balance;
   }

   public double addInterestAll ()// I made this method myself but I am not sure if it is correct
   {
       balance += (balance * 0.03);
       return balance;
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Returns the current balance of the account.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public double getBalance ()
   {
      return balance;
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Returns the account number.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public int getAccountNumber ()
   {
      return acctNumber;
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Returns a one-line description of the account as a string.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public String toString ()
   {
      return (acctNumber + "\t" + name + "\t" + fmt.format(balance));
   }
}
```

Here is the main method that is under construction and I am not sure if I am on the right track:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class SixSix
{



public static void main (String[] args)
   {
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Input (0) to add account, (1) to deposit,");
      System.out.println("(2) to withdraw, (3) to add interest, (4) to add interest to all");
      System.out.println("(5) to get balance, (6) to get account number, (7) to print");
      int input = scan.nextInt();

  while (input == 0){
      System.out.println("To create an account, please enter your name");
      String name = scan.nextLine();
      System.out.println("Please enter your account number");
      int accNum = scan.nextInt();
      System.out.println("Please Enter account balance");
      double accBalance = scan.nextDouble();

      //System.out.format


  }

  while (input == 1)
  {
      System.out.println("To deposit money to an account");

  }

  while (input == 2)
  {
      System.out.println("To withdraw money from an account");

  }

  while (input == 3)
  {
      System.out.println("To add Interest");

  }

  while (input == 4)
  {
      System.out.println("To add Interest to all");
  }

  while (input == 5)
  {
      System.out.println("To get balance");

  }

  while (input == 6)
  {
      System.out.println("To get account number");
  }

  while (input == 7)
  {
      System.out.println("Printing account");
  }


  }
}
```

Comment: what book is this if I may ask?

Comment: Java Software Solutions for AP* Computer Science by John Lewis, William Loftus, and Cara Cocking.

Comment: What is the question exactly? Do you just want to know if you're on the right track (I would say yes to that), or do you need help with actually creating the accounts? If so, is there something in particular you're struggling with, or just the general structure?

Comment: @Lidae I said that I wasn't sure exactly what the question was asking but what i don't know how to do is to allow the user to make accounts and use the methods of the class. I think that the assignment is asking for this to happen but im not certain

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me like you're on the right track. I'm inferring from the way the question (in the book) is phrased and the code that you've posted that the accounts don't already exist, in which case you need to allow the user of the system to create them. Then when altering an account, the user would first have to supply the account number so that you can identify the proper `Accounts` object.

I'm guessing that since the chapter was on arrays, it probably hasn't covered Maps yet (which would otherwise be a convenient way of associating account numbers to `Accounts` objects). If you use arrays, then having the account numbers range from 0 to 29 seems like a good idea.

Here's an example of how you could implement an `AccountsManager` class that helps you add and retrieve accounts from an array of accounts.

```
public class AccountsManager {
    private Accounts[] accounts;
    private final int capacity;
    private int current;

    public AccountsManager(int capacity) {
        this.capacity = capacity;
        accounts = new Accounts[capacity];
        current = 0;
    }

    // returns the account number of the new account
    // or -1 if no account could be made
    public int addAccount(String name) {
        if (current >= capacity) {
            return -1;
        }
        accounts[current] = new Accounts(name, current, 0);
        return current++;
    }

    public Accounts getAccount(int number) {
        if (number >= current || number < 0) {
            return null;
        }
        return accounts[number];
    }
}
```

In the above, the `capacity` attribute is simply the size of the array, which is the maximum number of `Accounts` objects that can be created (this should be 30, according to the exercise). The `current` attribute (feel free to rename to something more informative!) keeps track of where in the array the next `Accounts` object should be created. This grows by one each time an account is added.

In your code, you could now do something like this:

```
AccountsManager manager = new AccountsManager(30);

// ...

if (input == 0) {
    // Create new account
    System.out.println("To create an account, please enter your name");
    String name = scan.nextLine();

    int accountNumber = manager.addAccount(name);
    if (accountNumber == -1)
        System.out.println("The bank can't handle any more accounts.");
    else
        System.out.println("Your account number is "+accountNumber);

} else if (input == 1) {
    // Deposit money to account
    System.out.println("What is your account number?");
    int accountNumber = scan.nextInt();

    // Check if account exists
    if (manager.getAccount(accountNumber) == null) {
        System.out.println("That account doesn't exist!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("How much do you want to deposit?");
        double amount = scan.nextDouble();
        manager.getAccount(accountNumber).deposit(amount);
    }
}
```

Perhaps it might be preferable to create new methods in the `AccountsManager` class to make deposits etc, but this shows at least what the general structure could be like.

Comment: Thank you very much! However, will you please explain the usage of the capacity and current variables? I don't really understand whats happening in the code.

Comment: @Nub I added some explanations and some more example code.

Comment: Thank you again! I think I understand better. I appreciate your hard working effort.